# Non compact Seifert manifolds

Tags: 3-manifolds, fibre-bundles, orbifolds, seifert-fiber-spaces

A Seifert manifold $M$ is a $3$-dimensional orientable smooth manifold with an effective circle action with no fixed points.

Closed connected Seifert manifolds are classified up to an equivariant diffeomorphism, by the Seifert invariant that encodes the genus of the orbit space, together with data on the exceptional (non-free) orbits.

**Question:** Is there anything known about the classification of non-compact Seifert manifolds?

Naively, one may try to take the classification of non-compact surfaces, and define a new invariant by keeping track of the surface-type of the orbit space, and the data on the exceptional orbits (which will now be an infinite list), but it's unclear to me if this approach will work.

This can also be translated to orbifold language, if I'm not mistaken, to a question of classifying circle bundles over non compact $2$-dimensional orbifolds.

Edit: maybe I should've started by asking the same questions for circle bundles over non compact smooth surfaces.

Comment: Having a circle action (without a global fixed point) is more restrictive than having an orbifold circle bundle (even in the case of ordinary circle bundles!). Do you want an orientable circle bundle? Then you get two equivalent notions. The classification in the noncompact case is the same as in the compact case except you do not have the Euler class.

Comment: I was not aware that this is more restrictive - I'll read more about orbifolds, and in particular about the interplay between orbifolds and seifert fibrations.

Comment: Regarding the second part of you comment, is this something that was worked out in a paper or book?

Comment: Have you looked at the classification of non-compact surfaces?  The non-compact Seifert fibered classification will look like a combination of that, and the classification of compact SF manifolds.

Comment: I do not think such a reference exists (Maillot did not do this either!), but you can prove it following the proof in the compact case.

Comment: I went over the proof in the compact case again, and I think that I understand and agree. I will accept an answer if any of you wish to write one.

Comment: Per your request, I have now put together a CW answer relying on the comments.  You might ask questions or possibly accept the answer (so that this question will be "done").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is copied, in part, from the comments.  So I've made it community wiki.  Please feel free to edit and improve.

---

The consensus in the comments is that "the classification in the non-compact case follows from the classification in the compact case".  Here are a few details.

Suppose that $M$ is a oriented, connected, smooth three-manifold (possibly with boundary).

**Definition:** Suppose that $M$ is equipped with a smooth circle action $\sigma \colon S^1 \times M \to M$ so that, for every point $x \in M$, the orbit map $S^1 \to \mathcal{O}_x = S^1 \cdot x$ is a covering map.  Suppose also that, away from an isolated collection of *exceptional orbits*, this degree is one. Then we call $\sigma$ a *Seifert fibre structure* on $M$, and we say that $M$ is *Seifert fibered*.

**Definition:** Suppose that $\sigma$ is a Seifert fibering of $M$.  We use $B = M/\sigma$ to denote the *base orbifold*: that is, the quotient of $M$ by the $S^1$ action, where the classes of exceptional orbits are marked by the degree of their covering.

**Definition:** We call two Seifert fibre structures $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ on $M$ *orbit equivalent* is there is an isotopy of $M$ taking the orbits of $\sigma$ to the orbits of $\sigma'$.  If all Seifert fibre structures on $M$ are orbit equivalent then we say that the fibering is *unique*.

For example, the solid torus $S^1 \times D^2$ has infinitely many inequivalent Seifert fibre structures.  Doubling, we find that the same is true of $S^1 \times S^2$.  However, if $M$ is compact and the base orbifold $M/\sigma$ is "sufficently complicated", then the fibering is unique.

**Classification in non-compact case:** Suppose $M$ (oriented, connected, smooth three-manifold) admits a Seifert fibre structure $\sigma$.  Then $\sigma$ is unique, unless it is homeomorphic to one of the known counterexamples in the compact case (perhaps minus some boundary components).

**Proof:** Let $B = M / \sigma$ be the base orbifold of the given fibering.  If $B$ has finite topological type then we are (essentially) in the compact case.  Suppose instead that $B$ has infinite topology. (So, infinite genus, infinitely many ends, infinitely many classes of exceptional orbits, or some combination of these.)

Suppose now that there is another Seifert fibering $\sigma'$ of $M$. Suppose that the new base orbifold $B' = M / \sigma'$ has finite topological type.  Thus $M$ admits a horizontal surface of finite topological type.  This covers $B$, a contradiction.

So $B'$ has infinite type.  So $\sigma'$ admits (essential) vertical tori.  These, again, cannot be horizontal surfaces with respect to $\sigma$.  So they are isotopic to vertical surfaces.  Taking a maximal (but locally finite...) collection of vertical tori gives the desired isotopy. $\Box$

---

Hmm. There may be a subtle point here.  Why is there a maximal locally finite collection of vertical tori?  If no such collection exists, then I do not see how to promote a collection of vertical tori to an isotopy of Seifert fibered structures.

Comment: Can you please give more details about the last paragraph in the proof? More specifically, I do not understand what you mean by "So $\sigma'$ admits vertical tori".

Comment: Suppose that $\alpha$ is a simple closed curve in the base orbifold $B'$.  Then the preimage of $\alpha$ is a "vertical torus" in the Seifert space.  If $\alpha$ is essential in the base orbifold, then its preimage is essential in the Seifert space. Cutting along essential vertical tori is how we can turn one non-compact thing into lots of compact things.